# How could I join an IRC channel in-browser using JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, irc, webrtc

I'm building a decentralised peer-to-peer application that uses WebRTC, and as part of its bootstrapping process I require to get nodes from a dynamic source.

The [IRC bootstrapping method](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Network#IRC) that Bitcoin used to employ worked by joining an IRC channel and decoding all the usernames into IP addresses to get bootstrap nodes. While this is not sustainable (and this is why they removed it) it did help get the clients set up automatically.

I understand that Freenode has implemented purely AJAX web chat using **qwebirc**, is there any way I could join a channel on Freenode by sending these AJAX requests from another domain?

Comment: qwebirc is open source, if you want to try to see how they have done this: http://hg.qwebirc.org/qwebirc/src

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I'll look through their code later and see what pages I can query with AJAX